# How to iterate through each value for each key in a dictionary in python 3.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a DAG in airflow, and have a dictionary similar to this one:

```
dict1 = {'a':['1','2','3'],'b':['1','2'],'c':['1']}
```

Each key represents a SQL file, and each value represents a table. I need to execute the SQL files on each value in their specific key value pair. I've already written the task necessary to execute the SQL, but I cannot seem to figure out how to run the loop properly so that it runs each key's SQL on each assigned value (table).

I've attempted:

```
dag_id = 'dag1'
@dag(
general dag parameters here
)

def dag():
  for i in dict1: 
     for table in i:
        operator = SnowflakeOperator(
           task_id=f'{dag_id}_{table}_{i}',
           OTHER PARAMS BELOW
        (
```

but I get a duplicate task ID error on run. I understand that I need to pull the actual values out of the key value pairs, but I am unsure how to do so.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Needed to include the key:value pair and then just iterate through the values. Spent far too long trying to figure it out and talked myself into an even worse answer.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's a built-in type.

Comment: also, if it's a dictionary, [surely you mean](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/) `for key,value in mydictionary.items()`

Comment: Apologies, that's not the real name in airflow but I was using it as an example. Will edit.

Comment: `i` is a key of the dictionary, so `for table in i:` loops over the characters in the key, not the values in that dictionary entry.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've attempted a number of iterations by pulling both and using dict1.items() but it has not worked out in my favor.

Comment: You want `for file, tables in dict1.items(): for table in tables:`

Comment: Definitely give that link a read though, understanding dictionaries is pretty core to Python.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yeah I appreciate the help. I started with what was really close to the correct formatting and eventually talked myself out of it over several hours of iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dict_1 = {'a':['1','2','3'],'b':['1','2'],'c':['1']}

Loop through both keys and values, by using the items() method:

```
for key, value in dict_1.items():
    print(key)
    for i in value:
        print(i)
```

you can loop only through keys using .keys() instead of .items() and only through values using .values()

[resource](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries_loop.asp)